# Background-Blend-Mode for multiple background images

Tags: css, background

I have this code:

```
BACKGROUND-IMAGE: url("Background-2.png"), 
url("Background.jpg");
```

How to apply `BACKGROUND-BLEND-MODE` only on `Background.jpg` and not on `Background-2.png`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
<div style="width:300px; height:300px; background-color:#FF0000;
    background-image:url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8543/br.png'),url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8545/tr.png');
    background-blend-mode:darken,lighten;">
</div>
```

Note the two values passed to the blend-mode style.  The first one affects the first background, the second affects the second.

https://jsfiddle.net/x7pjae50/

Based off the syntax I found here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode

If you want one to not have a blend mode, that is "blend mode normal."

Comment: And thank you, as well, as you just taught me that multiple background images are a thing and that they can be blended.  Very useful.

Comment: borken image links?